# Bootstrap 4 Accordion - The movement is not fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've realized an accordion using the **Bootstrap 4** [collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/).

When I click on the heading elements it opens the slide but the movement it's a bit stuck.

I would love to make it more fluid, what am I missing?

Here you can find a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davideoz/kn6sqacj/3/#save) that shows the behaviour:

**HTML**

```
<body >        
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_1" aria-expanded="false">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            Title First Slide
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse_1" style="">
            This is the first slide. 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_2">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            Title Second Slide
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse_2">
            This is the second slide. 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion .accordion-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.accordion .accordion-header .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-indent: 0 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.accordion .accordion-header .icon:after {
  /*background: #fff;*/
  border: 2px solid #f08e0d;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #f08e0d;
  content: "+" !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.accordion .accordion-header[aria-expanded=true] .icon:after {
  content: "-" !important;
  padding: 0px 13px;
}

.accordion .accordion-body {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying your code, it seems that the padding you are adding on the `.accordion-body` is affecting the animation a bit, by just removing that last rule the accordion opens up and closes smoothly

```css
.accordion .accordion-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.accordion .accordion-header .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-indent: 0 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.accordion .accordion-header .icon:after {
  /*background: #fff;*/
  border: 2px solid #f08e0d;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #f08e0d;
  content: "+" !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.accordion .accordion-header[aria-expanded=true] .icon:after {
  content: "-" !important;
  padding: 0px 13px;
}

.accordion .acc-content {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_1" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      Title First Slide
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse_1" style="">
      <div class="acc-content">
        This is the first slide.
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_2">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      Title Second Slide
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse acc-content" id="collapse_2">
      This is the second slide.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's true!! One more step on the way of the solution. Now I have just to find how to have a padding and keep the smoothness..

Comment: It's interesting how in the bootstrap collapse component example that I have linked there is a padding in the element and the movement it's still smoothing..

Comment: Why not adding a container inside the `accordion-body` and set the padding to it? check the answer again, I included this change

Comment: If you see the Bootstrap example has the padding on a component inside the body, so the padding is not included on the body itself; so when it expands it just shows the content inside without having to add padding to itself... Notice in the change I made, the first item has the class *inside* the body, the second item has the class *on* the body itself and the stutter happens

Comment: Thank you! now it's wonderful!
...I don't understand why somebody vote down my question..

Comment: I'd say it might be because you put a link to an external site; usually its better and easier for people if you add a code snippet in the question instead of sending people to another site; but it might be something else; In any case giving a read to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should help you avoid downvotes